# Is there any way to use OUTER UNION CORR in hive sql?

Tags: sql, hadoop, sas, hiveql

I am trying to create a table from four tables by using UNION logic, but all the tables have one column different.

```
PROC SQL;
    create table output_table
    select cl1, cl2, cl3 from  tb1
    OUTER UNION CORR
    select cl1, cl2, cl4 from tbl2
    OUTER UNION CORR
    select cl1,cl2, cl5 from tbl3
    OUTER UNION CORR
    select cl1, cl2, cl6 from tbl4;
quit;
```

On this query the output table contains all columns (cl1,cl2,cl3,cl4,cl5,cl6).

So my question is is there any way to get the whole column in Hive SQL please.

```
    create table output_table
    select cl1, cl2, cl3 from  tb1
    UNION ALL
    select cl1, cl2, cl4 from tbl2
    UNION ALL
    select cl1,cl2, cl5 from tbl3
    UNION ALL
    select cl1, cl2, cl6 from tbl4;
```

IF I use like this the columns on the output table contains only from the first table. (cl1,cl2,cl3)

But I need to get all columns on my output.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: `outer union` and `outer union corr` are strictly SAS as far as I know.  Gordon's answer below is how to accomplish it in SQL.

Comment: I removed the Teradata tag because the question explicitly talks about Hive.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select cl1, cl2, cl3, null as cl4, null as cl5, null as cl6 from tb1
union all
select cl1, cl2, null, cl4, null, null from tbl2
union all
select cl1, cl2, null, null, cl5, null from tbl3
union all
select cl1, cl2, null, null, null, cl6 from tbl4;
```

Comment: You have to be careful with data types in unions like this, nulls in the first query will be integers (at least in Teradata).  For ex, if c14 in tbl2 is varchar, this will fail.

Comment: Is this help me to get all the column and records on my output?

Comment: Yes, You have to include placeholders in the SELECT. And in the first SELECT, be sure to `CAST(NULL AS _the_correct_datatype_) AS _placeholder_name_`.